# I´m can´t connect MySQL. Follow message:

Tags: mysql

[Window Title]
Information

[Content]

### Service MySQL can not start. Reason:

mysqld: Could not create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL application
to log to the Windows EventLog. Run the application with sufficient
privileges once to create the key, add the key manually, or turn off
logging for that application.

[OK] [Cancel]

Answer (score 1):

run MySQL by running **cmd.exe as an administrator**. this will allow to create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL application to log to the Windows EventLog.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Was it helpful ?